# When I decompress a zip file on my Mac, the folder is nowhere to be found. Help!

Tags: macos

Normally when I open a zip file, the contents immediately open up in the form of a decompressed folder. For some reason, the unzipping process appears to be happening but then nothing opens. Any experience with this?

also - around the same time, I've started noticing that if I save something to my desktop, it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: Check your Archive Utility preferences (see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36115/unzipping-in-my-downloads-folder/36160#36160)), and see if "Reveal expanded item(s) in Finder" is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try relaunching Finder by

1. **System Preferences** -> **Force Quit**
2. Scroll down till you see Finder.
3. Click **Relaunch**